# Is there an function in C++ for picking numbers inside a string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, integer

I have a calculator from stacks in c++, and when i try to insert a formula on it like 1+2*3 I wish i had a function that would get the numbers until each character that isn't a number.
Example 12+2 it would get 12, then would skip the + because the code would get in other section and then again get the number 2.
I made something like

```
for(i=0;i++;i<string.size();)

 {
    if(string[i]<48)
    character(string[i]);
    else if (string[i]>=48)
    number(string[i]);
 }
```

But this isn't efficient, someone knows a function for it?

Comment: `std::stringstream` is purposed for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't exactly one function to do what you want, but there's still more support for it than most people realize. When you read a number from a stream, it knows to skip white space before the digits, so even if the stream contains something like "     1234", you can just read an integer, and get `1234`.

The stream, in turn, uses a locale to tell it what is or isn't white space, and should therefore be ignored while it's trying to read a number. A locale, in turn, is basically just a collection of facets. The facet that's used to classify whether a character is whitespace or not is a `ctype` facet.

So, to get what we want, we need a `ctype` facet that classifies all characters into two categories: digits, and whitespace. To get that, we can do something like this:

```cpp
struct digits_only: std::ctype<char> {
    digits_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table() {
        // a table with one entry for each possible value of char.
        // we'll start with it classifying everything as whitespace:
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask>
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        // now fill in the digits to say they're digits:
        std::fill_n(&rc['0'], 10, std::ctype_base::digit);
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

So then we need to create a stream, tell the stream to use a locale with that facet (called "imbuing" the stream) and then we can read our data as if the numbers were all it contained:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::string input("1+2*3/(44+55)");
    std::istringstream buf(input);
    buf.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new digits_only()));

    int value;
    while (buf >> value) // just read numbers from the stream
        std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

[I've embellished the string a little bit (added some parens and a couple of two-digit numbers).]

The result is fairly boring, but shows what (I believe) you're asking for:

```
1
2
3
44
55
```

Comment: This site is really amazing, thank you this was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if it's just going to work for integers you can use the evergreen atoi() from stdlib here 's the documentation https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/ , there are also the atof() and atol() that makes the same but with double and long int

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, your `foor loop` is completely wrong. In any C++ resource (e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_for_loop.asp) you'll see that there are only 3 statements:

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {}
```

Statement 1 is executed (one time) before the execution of the code block.

Statement 2 defines the condition for executing the code block.

Statement 3 is executed (every time) after the code block has been executed.

**Second of all**, why not give a try to [is_alpha()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)? I think this will answer to your question. Of course you still need to iterate over string.

**Third of all** - there is a ton of examples for such calculator online. Just look around.

Comment: sorry the for loop was wrong because i didn't have a computer with me i just coded it from my mind and got it wrong lol haha, is_alpha() doesn't work for me becuase it just get the alphabet and not the '/, *, +, -' characters.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), but skipping all non-digits instead of just whitespace?

The usual solution is to first tokenize the string into substrings such as `{"1", "+", "2", "*", "3"}` and then convert the tokens appropriately. Trying to recombine your numbers `1, 2, 3` with your operators `+,*` afterwards seems messy and error-prone.

---

BTW, using magic numbers like `48` in your code is poor style, for a number of reasons:

1. repeated magic numbers are a bad idea anyway, because it's hard to read and much to easy to mis-type just one of them as 49, and have a hard time finding it
2. if you really must hard-code the ASCII code for `0`, consider `0x30` instead of `48` - the hex values of the digits are much more readable IMO
3. but ASCII is a platform detail (albeit a fairly ubiquitous one), so it's better not to hard-code that at all
4. you don't need to write any character classification yourself anyway *whatever* the encoding: just use [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/locale) etc - that's what they're there for

Comment: Yeah isdigit() works fine but it only works if the string has just 1 number if it has like 10*6 it does not get the 10 it get 1 then 0 then 6

Comment: Yes, you need to run it in a loop, or use `find_if_not(begin, end, isdigit)` or something